# Identify the hashing algorithm

Tags: hashing

I started working on a web scraping project and wanted to generate the URLs to be able to scrape the data. In my company's website, unique URL is by converting Listing ID to hash value of length "7". I am trying to generate the URLs, but could not identify the underlying hashing technic applied on the Listing ID. Below image shows ListingID, Hash and sample Website URL.

[image: link to image]

Below are the hashing technics I have tried but none of them worked. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

```
CRC-16 CRC-32 MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA224 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512
SHA512/224 SHA512/256 SHA3-224 SHA3-256 SHA3-384 SHA3-512 Keccak-224
Keccak-256 Keccak-384 Keccak-512 Shake-128 Shake-256
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Is there no documentation at your company related to the hash algorithm used to generate part of the URL?

Comment: What makes you think it is a standard algorithm.  Anyone can invent their own technique for hashing.

Comment: Taking what others have said a step further, are you sure it's a hash? It could be a random value assigned to every ID.